# How to use wglUseFontBitmaps in ArcGlobe?

Tags: arcglobe

Does anyone have any experience using, wglUseFontBitmaps in ArcGlobe.

It seems no matter what I do, the text doesn't show up on the globe.

Here's my code.  This is the same way that I've plotted points, drawn polygons, polylines, etc on the globe.  Any help would be great.

```
double outX = 0;
double outY = 0;
double outZ = 0;

myGlobeViewUtil.GeographictoGeocentric(0 ,0 ,0 , out outX , out outY , out outZ);

Font font = new Font("Courier New" , 32.0f , FontStyle.Bold);
uint dbase = GL.genLists(256);
wglUseFontBitmaps(this.Handle, 32, 256 , dbase);

GL.glLoadIdentity();
GL.glTranslatef(0.0f , 0.0f , -1.0f);

GL.glColor3f(1.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f);
GL.glRasterPos3d(geoX , geoY , geoZ);
GLPrint("TEST");



private void GLPrint(string inText)
{
  GL.glPushAttrib(GL.GL_LIST_BIT);
  GL.glListBase(dbase -32);
  GL.glCallLists(text.length , GL.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT , text);
  GL.glPopattrib();
}
```